# Is there a fix for saveGIF in R when it stacks plots on on another in the output file?

Tags: r, animation

I am using R.  I have plots generated and stored in a list.  I would like to use `saveGIF(·)` to create an animation with these plots.  However, when I run the syntax, it generates a *.gif with every successive plot added to all the previous plots.  (And to boot, some of the plots have excessive gray backgrounds for no apparent reason.)

I'll include my code here if anyone might be able to help with this.

```
library(animation)

data("anscombe")
x <- anscombe$x1
y <- anscombe$y1
n <- nrow(anscombe)

lm.out <- lm(y~x)

M.x <- mean(x)
M.y <- mean(y)

plots <- list(1)
for(jj in -40:20) {
    b <- tan(atan(lm.out$coef[2]) + pi/180 * 0.8 * jj)
    a <- M.y - b * M.x

    plot.new()
    par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
    plot(x,y, pch=16, bty="n",xlim=c(2,15),ylim=c(3,12))
    points(M.x,M.y,col="lightblue3",pch=16,cex=1.6)
    abline(a,b,col="blue", lty=2)
    y.fit <- a + b*x
    points(x,y.fit,col="blue")
    for(ii in 1:n) {
        lines(x[c(ii,ii)],c(y[ii],y.fit[ii]),lwd=2,col="red")
    }

    plots[[jj+41]] <- recordPlot()
}

saveGIF({
    for(ii in 1:61) { replayPlot(plots[[ii]]); plot.new(); }
    }, 
    movie.name = "slope_change_best_fit_line.gif",   # name of your gif
    interval = 1/10,                    # controls the animation speed
    # fps = 20,
    ani.width = 800,                   # size of the gif in pixels
    ani.height = 800 )                 # size of the gif in pixels
```

Comment: fwiw...when I ran the code on a PC, it worked...I'd still like to know why it doesn't work on a mac